# AngularJS Select item for the element to edit

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-select

I want to know how to put an element selected in select that is alimented with data from JSON coming from REST API :
here is my code :

```
<select ng-model="TransferCtrl.transfert.driver" ng-selected="TransferCtrl.transfert.driver.id == d.id">
 <option ng-repeat="d in TransferCtrl.drivers" value="{{ d }}">{{ d.firstName }}</option>
</select>
```

and here is my logic in the controller :

```
StaffService.getAllDrivers().then(
        function(response){
          vm.drivers = response.data;
        },
        function(error){
          console.log('error : ' + error)
        }
);
```

and the selected driver is showed in a modal to be edited,so I want that the driver be selected in the list on the edit time,how proceed please ?

Comment: Please do a little research before you post a Question.

Comment: I have searched many times but no solution found formy problem.

Comment: `ng-model` is enough to assign the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to set your selected item to a variable `$scope.selectedItem` when your `select` has changed.

PS. Don't use `ng-repeat` on select but use `ng-options`.

```
<select ng-options='d.firstName for d in TransferCtrl.drivers' ng-change='selectedTemplate(d)'></select>
```

controller:

```
$scope.selectedTemplate = function(item){
  $scope.selectedItem = item;
}
```

modal:

```
<div>
  <h1>selectedItem.firstName</h1>
</div>
```